# Is there any way to create a high level language interpreter implemented in hardware?

Tags: compiler-construction, programming-languages, hardware, interpreter, hdl

Some random thoughts caught me and I just cannot get it out. I am thinking since morden processors are just interpreters for different kinds of assembly languages, is there anyway to create some high-level language interpreters directly implemented in hardware, using some HDLs or even directly designed using logic gates?
Meanwhile I am thinking why this is not done yet, some reasons that I can think of now are:

- Theoretical reasons -- It is theoretically impossible, though in my opinion it is possible since either cpus we already have or the machine we are talking about is just a variant of Turing machine so there is no difference in their natures, but I am not 100% sure about this.
- Design complexity -- It's generally too difficult to create such a complex machine.
- Speed drawbacks -- Even it is properly designed and implemented, it still cannot win because their speed will be a disadvantage of it.

I am just generally curious about this problem.

Comment: It's certainly possible in theory: Any sequence of traditional low-level instructions could potentially be implemented as a single high-level instruction. I believe you list many of the reasons it hasn't been done in your post. Generally, I think lower level implementations are a lot more efficient because it means that less rarely-used complex functionality lies dormant on the chip.

Comment: but if we are dealing with one specific language, all the language features will be frequently used and thus result in a neater design isn't it?

Comment: Read the original "Lambda the ultimate opcode" paper: http://library.readscheme.org/page1.html

Comment: And take a look at Forth processors

Answer (score 3):

Ever heard of [LISP machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_machine) or the company [Symbolics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolics).

I know the answers is short and is mostly links, but the answer is self contained.

Comment: The initial [CADR machine](http://www.unlambda.com/lispm/memo528.html) implemented a Lisp, but the commercial implementations generally implemented something that C could run on. Of course, they had microcode that helped with memory safe languages. For example, upper hidden bits of the 40-bit words helped with the memory manager and type flags (int, float, vector, etc). This actually allowed C programs to run on it but get overflow and pointer traps that they wouldn't receive on a regular CPU. So, really, they were just microcoded to be safe, and had a Lisp operating system.

Answer (score 2):

This has already been done [The Java processor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_processor).

Would this not be a very complex instruction set computer (VCISC) which leads to physically large processors. Some parts of the language are not used as often as others, this results in rarely used sections of processor, wasted silicon area.

Bigger die sizes for the processor increaes yield loss which increases the price for the end user. The economics of this favour smaller simple processors.

Low power processor designs are tending to favour RISC over CISC architectures. Super computers such as [Deep Blue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Blue_%28chess_computer%29) used many RISC cores. Most mobile communication devices use [ARM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_core) RISC cores.

Answer (score 2):

Burroughs famously had "Algol in hardware" [(see B5500)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burroughs_large_systems).

Less known is Burroughs beautiful  [B1700](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burroughs_B1700), which let each process define microcode to interpret the HLL that the process code used.  So, each process could have a *different* HLL instruction set; the hardware switched microcode sets on a context switch.

A lesson from the RISC world is that is more economical (and you get a larger market) to build a conventional instruction set, and compile the code for your language down to those instructions.  The DEC VAX tried to have language-specific instructions; it turned out to be faster to use the more conventional VAX instructions instead of the specific ones.

If you insist, it is probably relatively easy to implement a HLL instruction set using an FPGA. (I can imagine this being a graduate student project in an EE design class).   It just won't be performance competitive with an x86 or other modern RISC chip.

Comment: But why is it slower than RISC machines? Is there some general reason behind it?

Comment: "It"?  All the complex machines by definition are "complex". They have lots of internal decoding and delays.  Risc machines by definition try to be minimalistic in terms of complexity and therefore decoders. Hardware not needed for complex decoding can be invested in other accelerators, such as pipelines, caches, etc.